# HttpClient Authentication, Staying logged in

Tags: java, httpclient

So my goal is to login to a forum using httpclient, and then post a reply to a thread on that forum. I log in fine, but then when I go to post on the thread it says I am not logged in. Any Ideas? I have tried building the httpClient with cookies, but then I looked at them after I logged in and nothing was there. So I tried using the same httpclient for both calls but still didnt work.

```
String username, password, threadNum, bumpMessage, bumpTimer;
HttpClient http;

    public void login() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {

        this.http = HttpClients.createDefault();



        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.sythe.org/login.php?do=login");


        // Request parameters and other properties.
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("do", "login"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("url", ""));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vb_login_md5password", this.password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vb_login_md5password_utf", this.password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("s", ""));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vb_login_username", this.username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vb_login_password", ""));



        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

        //Execute and get the response.
        HttpResponse response = http.execute(httppost);



        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    }

    public void bump() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
    {

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.sythe.org/newreply.php?do=postreply&t=" + this.threadNum);

        // Request parameters and other properties.
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", ""));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", this.bumpMessage));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wysiwyg", "0"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("iconid", "0"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("s", ""));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("posthash", ""));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("poststarttime", ""));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loggedinuser", ""));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("multiquoteempty", ""));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sbutton", "Submit Reply"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("signature", "1"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parseurl", "1"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emailupdate", "9999"));



        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

        //Execute and get the response.
        HttpResponse response = this.http.execute(httppost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("filename.html","UTF-8");

        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = null;

            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    writer.println(line);
                }
            } finally {
                instream.close();
            }
        }
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Edit: I got it working in python!

```
jar = cookielib.FileCookieJar("cookies")
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

def login():
    logindata = urllib.urlencode({'do' : 'login',
                                  'url':'',
                                  'vb_login_md5password' : password,
                                  'vb_login_md5password_utf' : password,
                                  's' : '',
                                  'vb_login_username': username,
                                  'vb_login_password': '' })

    response = opener.open("http://www.sythe.org/login.php?do=login", logindata)



def bumpThread():

    if(username == "Not set" or password == "Not set"):
        print "Please setup password!"
        return

    if(threadNum == 0 or message == "Not set" or bumpTime == 0):
        print threadNum
        print message
        print "Please setup thread!"
        return

    logindata = urllib.urlencode({'title' : 'The Thread',
                                  'message' : message,
                                  'wysiwyg' : '0',
                                  'iconid' : '0',
                                  's' : '',
                                  'do' : 'postreply',
                                  't' : threadNum,
                                  'p' : '',
                                  'posthash' : '',
                                  'poststarttime' : '',
                                  'loggedinuser' : '',
                                  'multiquoteempty' : '',
                                  'sbutton' : 'Submit Reply',
                                  'signature' : '1',
                                  'parseurl' : '1',
                                  'emailupdate' : '9999' })

    thread = opener.open("http://www.sythe.org/newreply.php?do=postreply&t=" + str(threadNum),logindata)
```

Comment: Is there any sort of token which is returned after login, which you are expected to use in subsequent calls to their secure web services?

Comment: I think its a cookie...(not a token). I got it working in python with cookies. As I said I tried with httpclient cookiejar but was not able to capture a cookie and attach it to the httpclient. I edited the original post with the python code. It definitely is a cookie I think now.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is to use a "closeable" httpclient instead (`CloseableHttpClient`). Also, try implementing cooking using `BasicCookieStore`. Create the httpclient object, do whatever requests you need, *then **close*** the httpclient.

There are also a few resources that may be helpful:

- Apache HttpClient documentation for "State Management": https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html
- Apache HttpClient example for logging in

Below is some example code I wrote that will log in using a POST request, then send a GET request that verifies the login worked.

Here is how my login feature is implemented:

1. Setup **proxy** using `CredentialsProvider`
2. Setup **cookies** using `BasicCookieStore`
3. **Build a custom HttpClient** using `CloseableHttpClient`
4. Setup **POST Request**: target, host, parameters, paths
5. **Execute** POST Request to `/login.html` to log in.
6. Execute a GET Request to `/user` to see if we logged in correctly
7. Print status code of response

   ```
   //////// SETUP
   //Setup Proxy (If needed)
       CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
       credsProvider.setCredentials(
               new AuthScope("proxy.mycompany", 8080),
               new UsernamePasswordCredentials("my_username", "my_password"));
   //Setup Cookies
       BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

   //Build HttpClient
       CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
               .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
               .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
               .build();
       HttpHost target = new HttpHost("www.mycompany.com", 80, "http");
       HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxy.mycompany", 8080);
       RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
               .setProxy(proxy)
               .build();
   try {
   //////// LOGIN REQUEST, POST TO /login.html
   //Start POST Request
       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost('/login.html');
   //Add parameters to POST Request
       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();   
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair('username','my_username'));  
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair('password','my_password'));
       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
   //Set Config for POST Request
       httppost.setConfig(config);
   //Execute POST Request
       httpresponse = httpclient.execute(target, httppost);
   //Print Response Code
       try {
          System.out.println("Status Code: "+httpresponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
       } finally {
   //Close HTTP Reponse (must be in a 'finally' block)
           httpresponse.close();
       }

   //////// CHECK LOGIN STATUS, GET TO /user
   //Start GET Request
       HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet('/user');
   //Set Config for GET Request
       httpget.setConfig(config);
   //Execute GET Request
       httpresponse = httpclient.execute(target, httpget);
   //Print Response Code
       try {
          System.out.println("Status Code: "+httpresponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
       } finally {
   //Close HTTP Reponse (must be in a 'finally' block)
           httpresponse.close();
       }
   } finally {
       httpclient.close();
   }
   ```